# How to create a pop-up window in Conversation Page?

Tags: java, android

I wanted to use "AlertDialog" to create pop-up window in Conversation Page, but system showed " Unable to add window".

Hi, I wanted to create a "Strong-Remind" function : The user could bookmark one particular contact / group, and his/her phone will vibrate for 5-10 seconds when the user receives the message sent by the particular contact/group.

In my design,the user can stop the vibrate when they click the "confirm "button in pop-up window, but it cannot be achieved, I tried to add this function in mobicomkit\src\main\java\com\applozic\mobicomkit\api\notification\NotificationService.java, the vibrator has been created and worked well, but the pop-up windown cannot be created.

```
public void warn(){
    vibrator = 
 (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    long[] pattern = {100, 400, 100, 400};
    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 2);
    final  AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder2.setTitle("Warning")
            .setMessage("You have one important message !")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                    vibrator.cancel();
                }
            })
            .show();

 }


 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add 
 window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:785)
    at 
 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:352)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final  AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

This **context** you passed is not a valid context , you could try another.

Comment: The problem I guess is "The UI for the page is not in this package, but the AlertDialog.Builder requests an UI to implement with", may I ask if it is the reason.

Comment: I wonder to try "getApplicationContext()" but the class cannot extends Activity or AppActivity, so it cannot use lol

Comment: You can pass an context to this class, but you should concern about memory leak .  where did you user __warn__ method?